# How to use Prometheus to gather custom metrics from multiple pods in Openshift

Tags: openshift, prometheus

Right off the bat, my tech knowledge of OpenShift is pretty limited so please forgive any incorrect use of terminology here.

Let's say I have a site that is called MySite. We want to expose some metrics that show customer activity like Account Open, Account Closed, and Account Locked. These custom metrics are exposed on MySite/metrics.

The issue is with multiple pods. From what I understand, if you use the basic method like I showed above you will only get the metrics from one pod. What is the correct technique for getting metrics from all pods? I'd like to be able to configure Prometheus to get data from all pods.

Others working on the team are taking a labor intensive approach to gather these metrics and it just does not feel right. It seems like there should be better options within Prometheus and OpenShift. It seems like this should be a common enough problem that needs to be solved.

If someone could point me in the correct direction, I would appreciate it. I did dig through some older questions but at least the ones that I found seemed to not be quite the same.

Comment: It seems like [this documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/monitoring/enabling-monitoring-for-user-defined-projects.html) directly addresses the topic.